# Remove CAS ticket from URL

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, cas

I'm having a problem with CAS. After a successful login CAS is redirecting me to an URL that includes the CAS ticket. This ticket is causing some problems when trying to manipulate the URL to access other entry points.

So, the steps are:

1. I navigate to the main URL of the app, and I'm redirected to the CAS login page
2. I log in successfully I'm redirected back to the main URL
3. The main URL includes the ticket

   ```
   http://.../.../secure/index?url=account/22222222&ticket=ST-8543-0lfLCbblbF9Z1Nk7ATUA-udcsg1ab
   ```

Any ideas about how to remove the ticket from the main URL after being redirected?

Answer (score 1):

The login process isn't yet complete.  CAS is redirecting back to your app with the ticket, which your app should then validate.  If the ticket is valid cas will return the username and password to your app, at which point the user is logged in.  They may then be redirected to the resource they were trying to access.

The process of validating the ticket and retrieving the user details should be handled by your CasAuthenticationProvider which is wired into your spring authentication manager.